# Creating new VPC on AWS is always creating a Route Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I am trying to create a new VPC (Not via Wizard) and my assumptions is it should not create any router along with it. It started happening from yesterday. Also i can not delete the router as it errors route because of dependencies. However when i delete the VPC it deletes the Router as well.

Comment: Did you specifically try AWS ec2 instance creation?

Comment: What do you mean by a "router"??? there is no such thing in AWS VPC.  There are route tables and other things that do routing but no "router"

Comment: @Vorsprung i was referring to the Route table. My apologies

Comment: @SatishPatel why would i create a EC2 ? All i am trying to do is create a VPC thats it and then move one to subnet and Route Tables etc ... Seeing default route table mapped to default VPC at the Route Table UI makes sense but not a new one mapped to my VPC

Answer (score 4):

Each VPC (whether created manually or using a wizard) must have / or comes with a router. See: [Route Table Basics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Route_Tables.html)

- Your **VPC has an implicit router**.
- Your VPC automatically comes with a main route table that you can modify.
- You can create additional custom route tables for your VPC.
- You **cannot delete the main route table**, but you can replace the main route table with a custom table

Comment: I understand that i get a default Route table which is the main route table when i create a VPC but i am seeing two route table when i navigate to Route Table UI from console . One is the main route table which is default which has a default VPC and another one which has no name but is mapped to my new VPC

Comment: You get a route table for each VPC. The "default" route table is not the DEFAULT route table for your account. It is the default route table for the VPC that is currently the default VPC. You can change a route table's name which I do recommend.

Comment: Think of a VPC as being your own private data center that is isolated from all other VPCs in your account and other accounts. Then some of the AWS nuances will make sense.

Answer (score 3):

When you manually create a VPC a default route table is ALWAYS created. You cannot delete this route table. You can edit this route table. To make this VPC accessible from outside the VPC you either need to add an Internet Gateway, a NAT Gateway or a Virtual Private Gateway.

The behavior for manually created VPCs that you are experiencing is normal.

Note: I am assuming that you mean Route Table and not Router. You have to first create the appropriate router (IGW, NAT, VPG) and then add that to the route table. If you use the Wizard, this is done for you, but for manually created VPCs you must do this manually.

Comment: I understand that i get a default Route table which is the main route table when i create a VPC but i am seeing two route table when i navigate to Route Table UI from console . One is the main route table which is default which has a default VPC and another one which has no name but is mapped to my new VPC

Comment: It's sounds like it's correct. One Route Table for each VPC. One RT for the default VPC and one for your new VPC

Answer (score 0):

Creating a VPC is followed by some integrated components as Router, a router is a part of VPC and can not be touched or replaced, AWS provide you a way that most of networking parts are managed for you so you need just to configure your route tables and the traffic will be routed as you wish by VPC.

The vpc router is a HA service with zero interruption, so you will lost all your network in case of a disaste.